# How to get custom address attributes in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-address, address-attribute

I am trying to display all custom address (Added programmatically) attributes on address add/edit page in My Account section.

I have looked into below interface

```
module-customer/Model/Address/CustomAttributeListInterface.php
```

It does have the getAttributes() function but the class which implements this interface is `module-customer/Model/Address/CustomAttributeList.php` and has

```
public function getAttributes()
{
   return [];
}
```

I don't know why the core team has left it like this. Was this intentional or this will get an update in next versions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a "hook" in the Open Source edition that the commercial edition ("Magento Commerce") uses to implement admin-managed [customer address attributes](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/stores/attributes-customer-address.html). This is one of the features that's exclusive to Commerce. While it's possible to add additional customer address attributes in the Open Source version as well using this same "hook," it must be done in code (or potentially managed by a third-party extension).